# How to remove a timer, after a session ends?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, iis-7, timer

I'm implementing an auto-refresh feature on a asp.net website.

The user does the login on the website, and if he goes to a specific page, which has a table that needs to be refreshed, a timer is created that refreshes the table.

But when the user logs out or the session expires, the timer keeps running. Now multiply this for X users, and we will have X timers running on the server.

What's the best way to get rid of the timers when they're no longer needed?

So far my code is the following:

```
protected static System.Timers.Timer _timer;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    ServiceStatus serv = new ServiceStatus();
    OutSubscricoesInfoV2 subscr = new OutSubscricoesInfoV2();
    serv = StreamerUtils.GetSubscricoesStreamer(ref subscr);

    if (serv != null && serv.success)
    {
        StreamerUtils.StreamerState strState = StreamerUtils.GetStreamerState(subscr);

        if (strState != null && strState.IsActive)
        {
            startAutoRefresh();
        }
    }

}

private void startAutoRefresh()
{
    if (Session["RefreshTimer"] == null)
    {
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

        _timer.Enabled = true;

        Session["RefreshTimer"] = _timer;
    }
}

private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //TODO: call refresh function
}
```

In my page, i have the following button which the user can click to refresh the table:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="RefreshCot" OnClientClick="javascript:StocksListControl.TriggerPostBack(); return false;" CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/refresh-title.png" />
```

Comment: This is very bad design, each of this timer is start a new thread, and you do not clear it after end. If you have some queries of work for each of your users consider to find some other way to do them.

Comment: Maybe you could create this timer client-side instead. So after x amount of time, you make a request to update the table, using javascript.

Comment: I don't see how a server-side timer can refresh a table. Is ElapsedEventHandler ever called?

Comment: _timer is static, which leaves you open to race conditions in startAutoRefresh().  Don't declare variables at a greater scope than necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the first comment to your question posted by Aristos, this is bad design.
For this situation I would suggest three options:

1. Use a asp.net Ajax control. An example can be found here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_ajax_control.htm
2. AJAX poling - Have the timers in JavaScript which will sit on the clients. Once the timer has passed its elapsed time, the client will make an AJAX request to the server (preferably calling a web service) to fetch the updated data. I would recommend using a JavaScript library for this such as JQuery. The documentation on their ajax function is found here:
   http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
3. Consider using a library that provides real time functionality such as SignalR, here is a link to the libraries site:
   http://signalr.net/

Now for the personal opinions; Of all 3 options, the 3rd will provide you with the most "elegant" solution. 
The 1st option will require you to use asp.net AJAX controls, which produce ugly HTML and can be a pig to work with. Also, timers on the client will be created which remove the true "real-time" aspects.
The 2nd option will again put timers on the client, removing the true "real-time" aspects. 
The 3rd option, will allow the server to be "aware" of connected clients, data shall be pushed to the clients, when available, via the use of "Hubs".

Whilst your'e at this learning curve crossroad, I would also recommend looking into some client side JavaScript design patterns to help structure your code on the clients. A great tool to use could be Knockout, found here:

http://knockoutjs.com/index.html

Here is a tutorial on how to use this with SignalR:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/322154/ASP-NET-MVC-SIngalR-and-Knockout-based-Real-time-U

The tutorial focuses on using ASP.NET MVC. I imagine this should be interchangeable with web forms, however, if the option is available to you I would recommend using MVC also.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the page already has a button, that when clicked, the table is refreshed. The code is the following:
`<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="RefreshCot" OnClientClick="javascript:StocksListControl.TriggerPostBack(); return false;" CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/refresh-title.png" />`

Also, before the start of the auto-refresh, I need to validate if the user has that feature subscribed. The auto-refresh should only happen if that's true. Can I do that with your 3rd option?